# Query with two joins and two tables

Tags: sql, join

For the simplification of the problem, lets say I have 2 tables:
**user**

- id: int

**ticket**

- id: int
- user_id: int
- marked: bool

With the given example data:

##### user

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

##### ticket

| id | user_id | marked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | false |
| 2 | 1 | true |
| 3 | 1 | true |
| 4 | 2 | true |
| 5 | 2 | false |
| 6 | 2 | false |
| 7 | 3 | false |
| 8 | 5 | false |
| 9 | 5 | false |

User 1 and 2 have marked tickets.
User 3 has 1 unmarked ticket.
User 4 has no tickets.
User 5 has 2 unmarked tickets.

And I need a query that returns **tickets** with **id** 7, 8 and 9 - the tickets of users who don't have marked tickets.

I've written the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket t
INNER JOIN user u ON t.user_id=u.id
INNER JOIN ticket tt ON u.id = tt.user_id
WHERE tt.marked = false;
```

But it doesn't works as expected. I don't want to use subqueries to exclude users with marked tickets. Can this be done fully with JOINs? So it happens that I'm not that familiar with JOIN clauses.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "But it doesn't works as expected" ? What does it do, and what does it not do ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a subquery?

Comment: Also you want to return id=7,8,9 because they are unmarked. but tickets 5 and 6 are unmarked too. why do you NOT want to return 5 and 6 ?

Comment: what rdbms?  mine doesn't have a bool data type.

Comment: You also should _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes `marked` is an `int`.  You may need to adjust your query to convert your `bool` data type.

```sql
with a as (
    select t.user_id
    , max(t.marked) as marked
    from ticket t
    group by t.user_id
)

select t.*
from ticket t
  inner join a on a.user_id = t.user_id
where a.marked = 0
```

I deliberately omitted `user` since it adds no value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hesitant to answer without more info, but subqueries may be helpful.
set up and post a repel for us to try it out.

If you're not familiar, here's a brief video on subqueries.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GpC0XyiJPEo&t=417s

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).